# Powershell is replacing whitespace in file

Tags: powershell

This might be unicode issue I'm not familiar with.
I've created a script to patch a bunch of machines at work, the patch includes adding a line to a configuration file (.ini). The configuration file must start with a blank line (don't ask me why). When I run the script the blank line at the start of the file now has a '?' character. No idea where it is coming from.

```
$computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Computer Name: ' 
$Path = "\\" + $computer + "\c$\Program Files\WinMagic\SecureDoc-NT\UserData\"
$fileName = $path + "SecurDoc.ini"

$content = Get-Content $fileName
$content[1] += "`r`nWMGAutoFix=1"
$content | set-content $fileName
```

Comment: What is your PowerShell version? What is the encoding of the source file and can you add a sample before and after? Also it looks like you are adding a blank line to the second line not the first

Comment: I figured it out thanks to you pointing me in the right direction. The script was converting files to ANSI by default and I was always checking the encoding of the file on my machine which i had already run the script against.
I was able to check on another machine and the encoding is Unicode. I added the -encoding Unicode flag after set-content and it works fine now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Powershell encodes files as ANSI by default. Solution was to use the following:

```
$content | Set-Content $filename -encoding Unicode
```